# Remap Keys in EMACS

Tags: text-editor, emacs, ide, lisp

### Specifically I want to remap the PAGE UP key to the HOME key and the PAGE DOWN key to the end key

page up   -> home
page down -> end

what should I add to the emacs config file.
Thanks.